# Integrating Custom Database with Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I Have a Wordpress Site with few users who are my college students

They Registered using their RollNumbers/HallTicket Numbers as their usernames in Wordpress site

Now I Have Another Database with Their Personal Details like Marks, Rank etc

Now I want to Integrate this Database to Wordpress so that when student/user logins , then he/her could see their respective marks and other details

I Just want your suggestions/ideas to implement this, Not asking for a Complete solution

Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We typically want to see that some effort has been made on your part to solve the problem yourself. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and what was the result?

Comment: @Greg I am just asking for an outline idea, Not asking the complete solution

Comment: Be more specific. Details on how you want it to work and so on.

Comment: There is an answer to your question here. And I agree with it. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6465/how-to-integrate-custom-database-table-in-wordpress-and-using-wordpress-function

Comment: @tntu Question Edited, Could u please Suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Google search for wp custom query has turned out a couple of interesting results.

I chose this one for you: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/writing-custom-queries-in-wordpress/

It should provide sufficient information if you can put it together with what you wnat to have done.

Comment: Thankyou for this, it wil help me a lot, but my only doubt is User should see only his data only from custom database table after login to wordpress site

Comment: We can use wpdb custom queries, but where we need to write our custom queries , we need to create a php file for that or we need to write it in an existing file ??

Comment: You can create a plugin for that.